# Series-parallel digraph problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

CS student here struggling with this one problem. Graphs are not really my forte, so I would really appreciate any help or proofs.

Let $G = (V, E)$  be a digraph, $a : E → R+$ a weight function defined on its arcs, and $x_0 ∈ V$
from wich any other vertex in $G$ is accessible. An $SP-tree$ for the triple $(G, a, x_0)$ is a directed rooted
tree of $G$, $T = (V, E'
)$ such that the cost of the path from $x_0$ to u in $T$ is the cost of the shortest path
from $x_0$ to u in $G$, for every $u ∈ V$.

(a) Prove that an $SP-tree$ always exists.

(b) Devise an algorithm that finds an $SP-tree$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.